# Ubuntu C++ executable

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I have a few doubs I hope someone can answer it.

I have an application I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`, `eclipse` and `C++`. What I want to do is compile my application and use it on other PC. When I try to run my executable in other PC it does not work.

I do not if I have to compile in a specific way, if I can use the executable generated by `eclipse` or if I have to compile with the libraries .... I am using the `OpenCV` libraries in my application.

So what I want is get an executable of my application and use it on other PC which runs `Ubuntu`.

Comment: afait `openCV` is dynamically linked, so you have to deploy the (i think it was) `.so` files of that library as well

Answer (score 4):

Compiling with Linux and moving the binary to another computer with (mostly) another Linux version is not a good idea! It will work in some cases but not all of the time! In most cases different libraries and library versions are also installed, .so files will not be found etc.(It's a big mess!) That is why a lot of programs in the unix world are released as source code!

--> Generate a Makefile to have your code compile easily 
--> Create your application in Java (probably not what you want...) 
--> Use llvm with llvm bytecode (not simple) 
--> Create a .deb file that installs the right binary and shows dependencies

Hope this will help you a bit.

Comment: I agree with your answer, except for the excessive use if the exclamation point!

Comment: Even I sometimes copy binaries between linux distributions - this is mostly for embedded systems with cross-compiled binary. For me it does not make sense for a desktop distribution. Nobody said this will not work - it will :) - but it is a mess and should not be done in my opinion!

Comment: Hi clambake, thank you for your answer. Actually My application it works in Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to run it in another Ubuntu 12.04.   In fact I have an ARM in wich I want to run my application at the end. So if I have my application which has been developer in a normal PC an x86 which is the best way to embebbed my aplication in the ARM, I know that I have to compile with the cross compile, but if I compile my aplication in my PC with the cross compile after Can I copy my application in the ARM and run it?? Do I have to make a special cross compilation??Thankss

Comment: @user3536692 You still cannot make sure that both Ubuntu machines have the same versions of certain libraries. Tools like `make`, `gcc`

Comment: ok, but then How Can I use my application in diferents PC??or in an ARM?? is that not possible??

Comment: You need a cross-compile toolchain

Comment: What I want is similar a .jar for Java

Comment: Thank jasal but How should be that cross-compile toolchain, I have already the toolchain for do it, but shall be a special compilation?? shall link the libraries?? I would like to see some axample or the stepts for do it. Thanks

Comment: You cannot create a platform-independent binary with C++

Comment: If you want to build for an ARM target you would have to use a dedicated toolchain like for example the Linaro ARM toolchain. It makes sure that the resulting binary runs on the target architecture.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no .jar for C++. As I pointed out you CAN use llvm to produce llvm bytecode which is platform independent (and fast) but you have to supply each needed .so file on runtime, this can be a big problem. Get a cross-compiling toolchain and use makefiles it is your best choice!